# How to change all my application texts (UILabel, UITableCell.....) color?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I would like to do something similar in CSS than "BODY {color:red;}" but in objectif C. I mean  if I have 10 differents UIView, I would like to change all the UIView texts color in one time.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Simple case - you somehow gathered them together

```
for (UIView *v in styledViews) {
    // apply current style here
}
```

I doubt that this is your case

#### Complex case - there are tons of styled views everywhere.

*Disclaimer: I can't guarantee anything about following code, it works on my simulator, which doesn't mean it will not blow up in user's hands. I wrote it because it was fun and may help Thomas to solve his problem. I didn't check documentation thoroughly because it's already 5 a.m. here*

1) Encapsulate style stuff in some `StyleManager` class (in this example `applyCurrentStyle:` will apply current style to any view passed to it). It should post notification each time style is changed (e.g. kStyleManagerNotificationStyleChanged)

2) Make `UIView` category (like `UIView+Style`) with public `setStyleManager:` method.

3) Implement it:

```
#import "UIView+Style.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface StyleSubscription : NSObject {
    StyleManager *styleManager;
    NSObject *subscriber;
}
@property (readonly) StyleManager *styleManager;

- (id)initWithStyleManager:(NSObject*)p subscriber:(NSObject*)s;

@end


@implementation StyleSubscription

@synthesize styleManager;

- (id)initWithStyleManager:(StyleManager*)sManager subscriber:(NSObject*)s {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        styleManager = [sManager retain];
        subscriber = s;
    }

    return self;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:subscriber 
                                                    name:kStyleManagerNotificationStyleChanged 
                                                  object:styleManager];
    [styleManager release];

    [super dealloc];
}


@end


@implementation UIView (Style)

static char styleSubsriptionKey;

- (StyleManager*)styleManager {
    StyleSubscription *s = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &styleSubsriptionKey);
    return s.styleManager;
}


- (void)styleChanged:(NSNotification*)n {
    [[self styleManager] applyCurrentStyle:self];
}


- (void)setStyleManager:(StyleManager*)sManager {
    if ([self styleManager] == sManager) {
        return;
    }

    StyleSubscription *subscr = nil;

    if (sManager != nil) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(styleChanged:) 
                                                     name:kStyleManagerNotificationStyleChanged 
                                                   object:sManager];
        subscr = [[[StyleSubscription alloc] initWithStyleManager:sManager 
                                                       subscriber:self] autorelease];
    }

    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &styleSubsriptionKey, subscr, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);

    [sManager applyCurrentStyle:self];
}

@end
```

Each time style manager posts notification correspondent views will be updated with a new style. View will unsubscribe from style notifications automatically upon deallocation. Style manager can be removed explicitly `[view setStyleManager:nil]`.

Comment: Thanks for a such detailled answer ... Its so complicated to so something really simple ;-(

Comment: Well, it's not so complicated if you take into account that this is what you need to do once. After that all you need to style any of your views (and keep it synced) is call `[view setStyleManager:styleManager]`. iPhone view model doesn't support CSS approach in any way so we have to code it somehow. I agree though that this is can be done much easier depending on circumstances. This two approaches are somewhat extreme cases (most simple and most automated/complicated). Between them are possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix this in a nice way.here is a tutorial

http://dot-ios.blogspot.com/2013/02/design-uilabel-in-optimize-way-for.html